Chromatography conversion
I'd like to know if there is a way to calculate the expected retention time when going from a UPLC 2.1x50mm, 1.7µm column to a prep HPLC analytical column that is 2.1x50mm, 5µm column.
Currently I have run some samples that effectively elute ~2x later on the HPLC column when compared to the UPLC run.
Ultimately I would like to provide some sort of spreadsheet/calculator to my chemistry team so when they run their UPLC analytical run they can do a quick conversion to determine what it would look like on the prep HPLC analytical column.
Thank you

Check your dimensions! Prep and analytical have same dimensions.
